# Site stuck on maintenance mode only for a single page

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode

On a live, multilingual (fr/en) client site, I've just update Drupal 7 to its latest version (along with a few modules). Everything went fine, except that, even though the maintenance mode has been disabled, the maintenance page still shows up on **ONE specific URL** of the public site.

www.domain.com/ -> OK
www.domain.com/fr -> **!!! maintenance page**
www.domain.com/fr/ -> OK
www.domain.com/en -> OK
www.domain.com/en/ -> OK

(All the other pages are OK, as far as I can tell.)

I've tried clearing all caches multiple times, and I tried running update.php again, with no effect.
Following other answers, I've also checked the database (cache_bootstrap and variables), but as far as I can tell, everything is normal there too.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**
Problem solved, although I haven't done anything in particular. Maybe it was caused by some third-party caching mechanism (e.g. from the hosting provider). Will look into that if the problem occurs again.

Comment: Are you using varnish, boost, or another external cache?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of those words, so I guess no. ^^ But you raise a good point: maybe the hosting provider does? I should look into that.

Comment: Actually the problem appears to have "fixed itself", so I guess it was indeed some kind of caching mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this scenario a few days back. In my case, the site was displaying maintenance page only on registration related pages in dev server.

After several hours of struggle, it was identified to be a huge secondary database (from PROD) which was connected only on enrollment related pages. I emptied the huge tables and the pages started loading seamlessly.

Hope this might help someone.